# How to create a Swift framework to be used by an Objective C application

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm trying to build a Swift framework that can be used by an Objective C app.

Setup:

- Xcode 6.1, iOS 8

Basic steps:

Creating Swift framework:

1. Create a new Swift iOS 8 framework
2. Create a single Swift class that is public and inherits from
   NSObject
3. Declare a single function, e.g. func doSomething(text: String)
4. Build the framework
5. Question: Where do I retrieve the output from? Derived data? Which
   folder? I tried to build the Release output by selecting Build for
   Profiling

Creating Objective C app:

1. Create a new Objective C app
2. Add the framework to the app project.
3. Question: How do I do this? It looks like embedding the framework as
   an Embedded Binary + Linked Framework should work. Is this correct?
4. Make sure "Embedded Content Contains Swift Code" setting is set to
   Yes

Result: Fail

Depending on how I create the framework and whether or not I target the simulator or device, I get either a linker error like this:

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC14BogusFramework9PublicApi", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol not found for architecture x86_64

...or...

I get a runtime error that it can't find Swift libraries:

dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib
  Referenced from: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/1B3E1AE0-05D5-4F3E-B866-FA2D46A17363/BogusFrameworkTestAppObjC.app/Frameworks/BogusFramework.framework/BogusFramework
  Reason: image not found

I've looked around a bit and found various options, but none have worked so far.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: From "Integrating Swift w/Cocoa & Obj-C": "...importing an external framework is the same whether the framework is written in a single language or contains files from both languages ... make sure the Defines Module build setting for the framework you’re importing is set to Yes."
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html

This tutorial runs through the requirements of building for different architectures, which each require a separate binary http://www.raywenderlich.com/65964/create-a-framework-for-ios

Comment: Thanks @mc01. I have Defines Module set for both the framework (it was be default) and the app (turned it on), but this does not appear to affect the results.  The raywenderlich.com tutorial is helpful, but I had assumed this info mainly applied to the pre-iOS 8 frameworks. I'm actually assuming that I can somehow stitch together the right architecture slices into a single binary, but it seems like even if I can get this working I'm likely to run into the Swift libswiftCore.dylib missing error. This seems way more complicated that Apple describes in their "Mix & Match" documententation.

Comment: This is an old post now, but there are working examples, both directly - like AlamoFire, or via cocoapods 0.36.  It is frustrating though, as the documentation does not provide clear and comprehensive examples / sample projects.

Comment: The second problem you had is related to not having the framework embed the swift runtime (embedded content contains swift code): https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1881/_index.html

Comment: Thanks @chrisco. Will check out those references. Note that Apple DTS gave me a post-build script, and although it appeared to link normally, it still did not work. They gave up asked me to file a bug. Also, I had tried setting: "Embedded Content Contains Swift Code" (see post). This is super frustrating because it simply does not work as advertised.

Comment: I guess you must be using Aggregate target. Through the build phases tab, have you already tried the following script: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/cromandini/1a9c4aeab27ca84f5d79/raw/48b1a7785c638cee39fc29bb24a78204616c565f/universal-framework.sh